# Bootstrap 4 columns align issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on making a site, and im currently dealing with BS4.1.3
I'm still new to this world so i have this issue right now:

```
        <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar sticky-top">
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-top-menu" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-top-menu">
                            <img src="img/baseline-menu-24px.svg">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                            <img src="img/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="40" height="40">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        Test
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="collapse" id="collapse-top-menu">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input-top-collapse-search" placeholder="Cosa stai cercando?">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

But the end result it's like this
[image]

While i wanted that the first blue button and the "logo" (B) were aligned, "test" a lot more in the right part of the navbar
Also the bottom search bar should be the same width as the container, so full lenght

Comment: normally, in bootstrap.css .form-control class has been set to width:100%. so if you dont change anything in your css your input should be full width. did you set width property  for 'collapse' class or 'collapse-top-menu' id in your css? or even for 'input-top-collapse-search' id?

Comment: <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="collapse" id="collapse-top-menu">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input-top-collapse-search" placeholder="Cosa stai cercando?">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

The whole css is in the HTML i've posted in the answer
But as you can see here, input-top-collapse-search and collapse-top-menu are present. How should i go to get it full width anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I am on mobile Stack Overflow app hence not able to test this.
In Bootstap 4, to put the test at the right of the navbar you can try,

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">The content which goes to right comes here as a li</ul>
```

Also for aligning the blue button (The button you are using here is called as **hamburger**, remember that) can be aligned by using some margin-top for it.

Just use a CSS selector to select the hamburger and give some **margin-top** property to it.

Please consider adding a codepen so that we mobile users can play around with your code.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your suggestion. I can't try them now, as my monitor broke, but I'll as soon as possible and let you know if it worked!

Comment: by removing the navbar-brand img, both hamburger menu and navbar-brand text are aligned perfectly
Also this is the codepen to try it out [here](https://codepen.io/vidrikdev/pen/EpGzam)
The problem now is that when the Menu opened, the input box doesnt fill the parent widht, more over there's a subtle movement of "Test" when i click the hamburger menu

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar sticky-top">
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-top-menu" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-top-menu">
                            <img src="img/baseline-menu-24px.svg">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8 pull-right">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                            <img src="img/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="40" height="40">
                            <span>Test</span>
                         </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="collapse" id="collapse-top-menu">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input-top-collapse-search" placeholder="Cosa stai cercando?">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

.collapse input{
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your suggestion! Gonna try as soon as I get my monitor fixed and let you know if this works!

Comment: [here](https://codepen.io/vidrikdev/pen/EpGzam) the CodePen
Unfortunately this doesn't work